# Creating an Outlook application/mail item without administrator right using a C# application that has administrator privilage

Tags: c#, exception, outlook, administrator

I have written a C# code that needs to have administrator right. Using this application, I am trying to create an Outlook application/mail item in order to open an outlook compose window. However, Outlook 2013 is already running without administrator right. I am using the following code, but since the created application/mail item and the already running instance of outlook have different privileges, it raises exception.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

**Is there anyway to create the application/mail item as current user instead of administrator (something similar to running a process as current user by providing username and password of the current user)?**

Outlook needs to be running without administrator right in order to have a functional indexing service.

Here is the exception details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
HResult=-2146959355
Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
Source=mscorlib
ErrorCode=-2146959355
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I came up with is to execute a secondary C# application as current user by providing username and password of the current user. This application is then responsible for creating Outlook mail/application item and opening compose message. This way the already running Outlook and the created mail/application items are both without admin right.

I simplified this further and even avoided using any secondary C# application by simply re-executing my original C# application but without admin right and passing input argument to it to create Outlook mail/application items.

This seems to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

No, if the security contexts are different, COM marshaling would explicitly refuse to work. This is a security feature designed to avoid a situation when security rights are elevated without an explicit user consent.

Comment: Yes. It does not work even with impersonation (LogonUser + Impersonate)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Outlook with admin privileges if you need to access a running instance from your application. The security context should correspond to your application.

Anyway, you may consider using Exchange Web Services instead. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information. Also you may consider using .net BCL for creating and sending emails.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, Outlooks needs to run without admin privilege in order to its indexing service work properly. It would be very much interesting to know about a way around this though!